# Serving NodeJS Server in a ReactJS project seperately

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, proxy-server

I am making an API request inside of a redux action. That API request is blocked due to a CORS issue. To solve this I made a proxy Express NodeJS server on the same project, that listens to a different port. 
This works great in development, on my local host. But in production(deployed on Heroku), I'm not able to serve the proxy server.

Part of the problem is I'm not sure what port to serve the proxy server in production, and how to serve it differently from the React App

**My API call**:

```
 axios.get(`/api/item-info`, {
            params: {
              productId: productId,
              variantId: variantId
            }
          })
          .then(response => response.data)
          .then(data =>
            dispatch(checkItemInventoryQuantity(parseInt(data.variant.inventory_quantity)))
          )
          .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

**My Express NodeJS Server**:

```
const express = require('express');

const request = require('request');

const app = express();

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
  );
  next();
});

app.get('/api/item-info', (req, res) => {
  const {productId, variantId } = req.query
  const username = process.env.REACT_APP_SHOPIFY_API_KEY;
  const password = process.env.REACT_APP_SHOPIFY_API_PASSWORD;
  request(
    { url: `https://${username}:${password}@semi-aquatics.myshopify.com/admin/api/2020-04/products/${productId}/variants/${variantId}.json` },
    (error, response, body) => {
      if (error || response.statusCode !== 200) {
        return res.status(500).json({ type: 'error', message: error.message });
      }

      res.json(JSON.parse(body));
    }
  )
});

app.listen(3001, () =>
  console.log('Express server is running on localhost:3001')
);
```